# Optimal MySql query to remove duplicate rows in a 1,500,000 record table

Tags: mysql, magento

I have a table in a Magento database called `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly`.
This table has over 1,500,000 rows due to an error a few years ago that created multiple unique records every day for a single product.

It currently looks like this:
[image]

I want to clean the database so that only one record exists per `period`, `store_id` and `product_id`, like this:

[image]

I tried 2 different queries but both seem to run for hours and then time out. I am wondering what is the optimal query to run on a large amount of rows?

Here is what I have tried based on SO research:

```
DELETE `duplicated`.*
FROM  `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly` AS `orig` 
INNER JOIN `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly` AS `duplicated`
ON (`orig`.`period`    = `duplicated`.`period`
    AND `orig`.`store_id`     = `duplicated`.`store_id`
    AND `orig`.`product_id` = `duplicated`.`product_id`);
```

I also tried this one:

```
DELETE a
FROM sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly as a, sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly as b
WHERE
          (a.period   = b.period OR a.period IS NULL AND b.period IS NULL)
      AND (a.store_id = b.store_id OR a.store_id IS NULL AND b.store_id IS NULL)
      AND (a.product_id = b.product_id OR a.product_id IS NULL AND b.product_id IS NULL)
      AND a.id < b.id;
```

I am currently doing this locally using MAMP Pro and Sequel Pro. The table I am trying to clean is over 110Mb. I don't know if this is a factor?

Comment: Temporarily creating a new table, then deleting the old table, then renaming the new table will likely be faster

Comment: Someone should correct me but, if your join conditions are having index, you should try to disable them and then try to delete.

Comment: Run your delete as a select to see how many rows you get back, if its more than the table itself, something is wrong. This might be the case since we cant see your entire table structure. Also, delete in batches of say 1000 using a where clause

Comment: Is it a simple case of changing DELETE to SELECT? I just tried it but get the following error: `Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'`

Comment: [Removing duplicates with unique index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647058/removing-duplicates-with-unique-index)