# Insert new column from existed column in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

I had data in my database. Now i want to add a column

```
$table->string('md5_url');
```

It work. But now i want to add unique index on md5_url. But it don't work because rows in my database have same value(=default value).
So what should i do if i want to create new column form existed column(such as i want md5_url = md5(url_column_value)

I have known 2 way to set default value.

```
$table->string('md5_url')->default($value);
```

and

```
$stack_links = DB::table('stack_links')->update(['md5_url' => $value]);
```

but 2 above way, the $value is fix, how to make it flexible (diffirent in each row) so that i can add unique index after that.

Note: i don't want to create model StackLink so don't try this way:

```
$stack_links = StackLink::get();
foreach($stack_links as $stack_link) {
   $stack_link->md5_url = md5($stack_link->url);
   $stack_link->save();
}
```

Update: have try

```
$table->string('md5_url')->default(uniqid());
```

but it don't work too.The result is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your column property like this:

```
$table->string('md5_url')->nullable();
```

It's okay now!

Answer (score 1):

Try `IGNORE` to set unique index to add new column.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('md5_url');
    });
    DB::statement('ALTER IGNORE TABLE listings ADD UNIQUE INDEX myindex (md5_url)');
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('md5_url');
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you, but it not work . uniqid() only return 1 random value, and all the row in the database get it

Comment: Oh, I see!! then you need to modify your value through some query.

Comment: there is already a question similar to yours here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647058/removing-duplicates-with-unique-index

Comment: no ,if i use ignore the duplicate will be removed. But i don't want to remove it. It only the init value of it. After i set unique index, then i will update it value = md(column_url_value)

Comment: you don't have any value initially, so there is no question of removing duplicate.

Comment: At the time a ask this question, i don't have nullable(), so that the value init = ' '

Comment: Do you really need to keep ' '?

Comment: no , as i said, after that i will set it value = md5(url_column_value). But before i set, i need to give it unique index, and values ' ' make me unable to set unique index. Btw, thank u for spending time to help me. I will upvote u . Many thanks!

Comment: sometimes talking helps us to find a better solution, that's what i am trying here too and i think we all have a better solution here on top that works for you and will works for others too.

Comment: Yes, i know. There are many way to help me to resolve the problem.So thank for all. But i will choose the simplest way , and that way can do all i need.