# Remove SQL duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, database, duplicates

I'm totally new in SQL. I never used it and just need a simple answer because I don't have time to learn SQL right now :(. I need to remove duplicated records from my local DB. Case looks like this:

```html
| id | type  | ... |
-------------------
| 1  | test  | ... |
| 1  | test2 | ... |
| 1  | test  | ... |
| 1  | test  | ... |
```

I want to remove all duplicated record which has the same `id` and `type` but leave only on record. Like this:

```html
| id | type  | ... |
-------------------
| 1  | test  | ... |
| 1  | test2 | ... |
```

Using delete by Id is impossible. I have 50k records and I want to remove all duplicated records. When ID and Type are the same.

Comment: What data is in the other columns, if those columns even exist?  What is the logic for _which_ record from each `id/type` combination gets retained?

Comment: Also what you want is not possible, your current data example does not have a order which we can use to order.

Comment: Please define which rows you want to keep, and how you can identify them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647058/removing-duplicates-with-unique-index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A TSQL sample code that might help:

```
 WITH tbl_alias AS
    (
       SELECT id, type,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY id, type ORDER BY id)
       FROM tbl
    )
    DELETE FROM tbl_alias WHERE RN > 1
```

Also you can try [How to delete duplicates on a MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-a-mysql-table)
.

Comment: MySQL 8 supporfs this only

Comment: Yes it works, maybe temp is not a suitable name. I changed it to tbl_alias

Comment: ["ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'test.tbl_alias' doesn't exist"](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wCuYEZyEQGVy3Eoq1jdZAC/0)

Comment: It's a tsql code and I tested it on Sql Server. Although the question is tagged with MySql, I just provided it in case it could be a help.

Comment: OK.. verified on SQL-Server. Strange feature.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

First Way

```
 SELECT id, type
        FROM table_name
  Group by id, type
```

Second Way

```
 SELECT DISTINCT id, type
        FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT` statement is used to return only distinct (different) values.

Inside a table, a column often contains many duplicate values; and sometimes you only want to list the different (distinct) values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name;
```

In your table

```
 SELECT DISTINCT id, type, ...
    FROM table_name;
```

Comment: (1, test, a) and (1, test, b) are distinct. But OP wants to keep only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use the keyword distinct when selecting mate.. try like this

```
 SELECT DISTINCT id, type, blah blah blah FROM your_table; // this should take care of em
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your table grouping by id and type, and using an aggregate function on the other fields.

You should add to your question the definition of your table and specify the rule to use to get the other fields. Anyway, this is a simple solution:

```
-- Create a temp copy of original table with distinct values
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE copy_table1 
   SELECT id, type, MIN(field3) AS field3, ...
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY id, type;

-- Empty original table
DELETE FROM table1;

-- Insert distinct data into original table
INSERT INTO table1 (id, type, field3, ...) 
    SELECT id, type, field3, ...
    FROM copy_table1;
```