# Remove duplicate based on 2 rows value

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

So I have a database with more than 2000 line and I wanted to delete the duplicate value based on 2 rows.
For Example :

```
no     server     name
1      serv1       a
2      serv1       b
3      serv1       b
4      serv1       b
5      serv2       a
6      serv2       b
7      serv2       c
8      serv2       c
```

So basically I wanted to remove the duplicate **IF** two of the rows have a duplicate
**BUT** I dont want to remove them if just one of the row has duplicate.

Expected Output:

```
no      server     name
1       serv1       a
2       serv1       b
3       serv2       a
4       serv2       b
5       serv2       c
```

Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to **delete** the rows in the table or just not show them in the result of a SELECT query?

Comment: I want to delete the rows in the table

Comment: Do you only have these two columns? Is there a primary key defined? What is your MySQL version?

Comment: I've edited the question. I have a ```no``` table which is a primary key, and my sql version is  ```5.7.21``` @Paul Spiegel

Comment: Then use the answer of Rakesh Jakhar and replace `id` with `no`.

Comment: You can also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647058/removing-duplicates-with-unique-index)

Comment: Okay, I'll try it. Thank you for the help @Paul Spiegel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many ways to do what you want.
If you 're looking for just `SELECT`ing the data without duplicates then you could use:

- *DISTINCT*

  ```
  SELECT DISTINCT Server,
                  Name
  FROM YourTableName
  ```
- *GROUP BY*

  ```
  SELECT Server,
         Name
  FROM YourTableName
  GROUP BY Server, Name
  ```
- *Window function (ROW_NUMBER) in a subquery*

  ```
  SELECT Server, 
         Name
  FROM
  (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Server, Name ORDER BY Server) RN
    FROM YourTableName
  ) TT
  WHERE TT.RN = 1
  ```

You delete the duplicates as

```
DELETE T1
FROM
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Server, Name ORDER BY Server) RN
  FROM T --YourTableName
) T1 JOIN
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Server, Name ORDER BY Server) RN
  FROM T --YourTableName
) T2 ON T1.RN = T2.RN
WHERE T1.RN > 1;
```

Comment: can you tell me how to delete the duplicate too?

Comment: You can't delete from a subquery - at least not in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct server, name
from t;
```

If you have a lot of duplicates, the simplest way is probably to recreate the table:

```
create table temp_t as
    select min(no) as no, server, name
    from t
    group by server, name;

truncate table t;

insert into t (no, server, name)
    select no, server, name
    from temp_t;
```

If you don't have many rows, then `delete` is fine:

```
delete t
    from t join
         (select server, name, min(no) as min_no
          from t
          group by server, name
         ) tt
         on t.server = tt.server and t.name = tt.name
    where t.no > tt.min_no;
```

Comment: Hey, @Gordon Linoff.do you know a way how to delete the duplicate data from the database too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to remove duplicates

```
DELETE t1 FROM tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2 
WHERE t1.id < t2.id AND t1.server = t2.server AND t1.name = t2.name;
```